# C# How to properly call/use .NET Framework 4.8 Windows Form

Tags: c#, logging, console

so i try to use a Windows Form (.NET Framework 4.8) RichTextBox as kind of Logger.
It is a fun project where i just want to have some inputs into it.

So, when i go into my Class (Also .NET Framework 4.8) and call the Class, i simply cannot edit or have inputs into the RichTextBox.

My other Class starts a Game Server for a Game. Whenever it started up, it should output something.

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine("[START] The Gaya Game Server has been started");
Console.WriteLine($"Time: {DateTime.Now}");
Form1 form = new Form1();
form.richTextBox1.Text = "[LOG] GAME SERVER HAS BEEN STARTED";
```

i also tried

```
using (Form1 main = new Form1())
{
     main.richTextBox1.Text += "[LOG] GAME SERVER HAS BEEN STARTED";
}
```

I always start the Windows Form first before starting my Game Server Console, so there'S no issue.
How do i make sure to call it and make an entry?

Thank you very much!

```
Console.WriteLine("[START] The Gaya Game Server has been started");
Console.WriteLine($"Time: {DateTime.Now}");
Form1 form = new Form1();
form.richTextBox1.Text = "[LOG] GAME SERVER HAS BEEN STARTED";
```

Comment: How is the `Form1.richTextBox1` configured? Is it `.Locked = False`, `.Enabled = True` and `.ReadOnly = True`? Also, is the `.Modifiers = Public`?

Comment: Locked = False | Enabled = True | ReadOnly = False | Public -> Yes, i also used it in a Class to test it. Maybe i need to update it after every entry?

Comment: You shouldn't have to update the Form if you're writing directy to a textBox.Text. I tend to not write directly to a text box on another Form but rather create a public property and within the property's `set {}` accessor, I write to the textbox.text... like so `public string LogText { get { return richTextBox1.Text } set { richTextBox1.Text += value; }`. But this doesn't explain why you can't write to the text box with your code. How do you open the Form1? In your code, do you instantiate the form every time your write to it or is it a global variable?